# reviced channel error on main func but no error in if reviced progrenn in goroutine

Tags: go

I send the data into channel by a goroutine.when I want to recievd it in main func,there is deadlock orrced at the last recievd of the channel,

```
package main
import (
    "time"
    "fmt"
)

func sender(ch chan string) {
    ch<-"chenl"
    ch<-"zhangs"
    ch<-"lisi"
}

func geter(ch chan string){
    for{
        var result string
        result = <- ch
        fmt.Println("print result %s",result)
    }
}


func main() {
    ch :=make(chan  string)
    //var result string
    go sender(ch)
    for{
        var result string
        result = <- ch
        fmt.Println("print result %s",result)
    }
    time.Sleep(10*time.Second)
}
```

the output:

```
print result %s chenl
print result %s zhangs
print result %s lisi
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()
```

but,if i replace the recived progress in a goroutine too,there is no error orrced.can someone help me,whe does this happed?

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "fmt"
)

func sender(ch chan string) {
    ch<-"chenl"
    ch<-"zhangs"
    ch<-"lisi"
}

func geter(ch chan string){
    for{
        var result string
        result = <- ch
        fmt.Println("print result %s",result)
    }
}

func main() {
    ch :=make(chan  string)
    go sender(ch)
    go geter(ch)
    time.Sleep(10*time.Second)
}
```

the output:

```
print result %s chenl
print result %s zhangs
print result %s lisi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example you have two goroutines: `main` and `go sender(ch)`.

The `main` is blocked after the third reading from channel and there is deadlock: `main` is blocked, `go sender(ch)` is finished.

In the second example you have three goroutines `main`, `go sender(ch)` and `go geter(ch)`. `Sender` and `getter` are working with channel while `main` is sleeping (without deadlocking). And when `time.Sleep` finishes, the `main` returns, and in Go, return from `main` ends the program, regardless of any other goroutines are running or not.

Comment: thankyou,I got it.but I think the main goroutine was blocked on the fourth received,because this time there was no data in channel.

Answer (score 1):

```
func sender(ch chan string) {
    ch<-"chenl"
    ch<-"zhangs"
    ch<-"lisi"
    close(ch)
}
```

The problem is that you don't close your channel when you are done producing more values and the `for` loop never end.

You should range over the channel and the loop will end when the channel is closed.

```
for result := range ch {
    fmt.Printf("print result %s\n",result)
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct. Also `fmt.Printf(...)` should be used to get formatted output. Code: https://play.golang.org/p/bMZk1EbBWJK